# How to return value from IronPython method to C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

After I execute the following code

```
    _engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var searchPaths = _engine.GetSearchPaths();
    searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
    _engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
    _scope = _engine.CreateScope();

    var pythonResult = _engine.Execute(

@"import sys
def testFunc():
    return 3"

    , _scope);
```

the C# variable `pythonResult` is `null`. I expect it to be equal to something I can invoke that returns `3`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You never call `testFunc` in your Python code. Try adding `testFunc()` after the definition.

Comment: Thank you!! Thought I tested that, must have been something else then..